# Which legendaries can you get from field research breakthroughs?

Tags: pokemon-go

[image: field research preview]

I know these achievement packs can give first generation legendaries. Does it give  legendaries from other generations as well?

Answer (score 13):

There have been:

**Legendary**

- April 2018: Moltres
- May 2018: Zapdos
- June 2018: Articuno
- August 2018: Raikou
- September 2018: Entei
- October 2018: Suicune
- December 2018: (Shiny) Articuno, (Shiny) Zapdos, (Shiny) Moltres,
  Raikou, Entei, or Suicune
- January 2019 - February 2019: (Shiny) Articuno, (Shiny) Zapdos, (Shiny) Moltres,
  Raikou, Entei, Suicune, (Shiny) Lugia, or (Shiny) Ho-Oh
- March 2019: Raikou, Entei, Suicune, (Shiny) Lugia, (Shiny) Ho-Oh, Regirock, Regice, or Registeel

**Non-Legendary**

- July 2018: Snorlax
- November 2018: Shedinja

Comment: This reward changes each month and update are sent in the game.

Comment: @Styxsksu This answer was posted prior to the game notifying which ones would be available, I've just been updating it as it goes. Plus. It didn’t send any notifications for the Regis